# Filter list inside list

Tags: android, kotlin, filter

My goal is to have the list object (Options) with just the filtered "tags".

```
     val gender = "MALE"
        val options: List<Options> = listOf(
            Options(id=1, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=2, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=3, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=4, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=5, tags = listOf("FEMALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=6, tags = listOf("FEMALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=7, tags = listOf("FEMALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=8, tags = listOf("FEMALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
        )

        options?.map{ itOptions -> itOptions.tags.filter{ it -> it == gender } }
        options?.forEach{ itOptions -> itOptions.tags.filter{ it -> it == gender } }
        options?.iterator()?.forEach { itOptions -> itOptions.tags.filter{ it -> it == gender } }
```

Images

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Result I expect
but the filter in the list does not happen correctly
**

```
        val options: List<Options> = listOf(
            Options(id=1, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=2, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=3, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR")),
            Options(id=4, tags = listOf("MALE", "JASMIN", "GIR"))
        )
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Will you please explain further, including more details about the expected result? Please include an example of the output you want.

Comment: `options?.filter {gender in it.tags}` will work as far as I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly, map and filter functions return a new list, they don't change the original list. You should assign the result to a new variable. Also your mapping is wrong. Try the code below.

val filteredOptions = options?.filter{ option -> option.tags.contains(gender) }

Comment: gooood...perfect....

Answer (score 0):

[Kotlin Playground Code Sample](https://pl.kotl.in/cYpHSyw4O)

options.filter { item -> gender in item.tags }

This is what are you looking for